# index.php is not in the public folder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I've done uploaded my fresh laravel project into a web hosting. Now it shows only a blank page. I use the pre-built login stuff in the laravel 5 and the link will is http://mylaravel.mywebhost.com/auth/login even if I enter http://mylaravel.mywebhost.com/public/index.php (as you know, index.php is in the public folder) and I didn't point my subdomain into the public folder. Any ideas, recommendations, clues, suggestions, help to make my laravel 5 work in my subdomain. Currently, I think it is because the index.php is in the public folder and my subdomain did not point in the public folder so the best way is to put the index.php outside the public but how I'm going to tell the laravel 5 that the index.php is outside the public folder like /index.php so that everything works again?

Comment: After reading it 3 times I still have *no* idea what your problem is. *"I didn't point my subdomain into the public folder..."* - why not?

Comment: i mean, usually when creating subdomain there is a field where your index.php is located

Comment: Yeah - so why don't you just tell it where the index.php is located? Every decent hoster should have an option to specify the domain's root directory, for Laravel projects it the public-directory.

Comment: `It shows only a blank page`, did you just clone this to your production server or something like that. Make sure to run `composer update`. I used to get the same issue.

Comment: Tell me more, what OS is on your server, what HTTP Web server you're trying to use, Apache, Nginx ? Did you set the configuration properly ? Show us more on what you did ?

Comment: @rangerover.js: yes I just clone it. im new in laravel 5 anyways

Comment: solve. thanks for the answer. I tried different approach to make things easier.

Comment: You said, I tried different approach, what is it ? After run `composer update` , do you still have a problem ? I'm just curious.

Comment: @CodeDemon : What do you think about my answer ? :D

Answer (score 0):

After cloning the project onto your **production/staging** server, you should do the following steps :

---

## 1 : fetch the newest version of your dependencies

run `composer update`

---

## 2 : Changing Permision on Storage & Vendor folder.

`chmod -R 777 storage/`

`chmod -R 777 vendor/`

---

Refresh your page.